# Can't connect to node js server with public ip

Tags: node.js, windows, amazon-ec2

I'm using aws e2c windows 2019 instance.I'm running node js servers with this code.

```
var http = require('http');
var today=require('./mynodedate')
var server=http.createServer(function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
res.write('<head><title>My First Node</title></head>');
res.write(today.myDateTime());
res.end('Hello World!');
}).listen(8080,"0.0.0.0");
console.log(server.address());
```

when i run this it runs succesfully and it prints "null".
if i access this server with private ip it works as i expected. but not with public ip.browser says"ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT".
i've checked my firewall even disabled it,
what am i missing ? can anyone help me?pls.
browser-chrome.

Comment: You're listening on port 8080, did you connect to the right port?

Comment: make sure you ec2 instance port 8080 is open for outside world `0.0.0.0:8080`

Comment: yeah i'm connecting to the 8080 port

Comment: how to check my ec2 instance is open for outside world

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My aws e2c instance port 8080 wasn't opened.Now I opened it and it worked.